# Simple login page--$_POST not in correct format?

Tags: php, html, curl

I have an html page and a login.php to set up a simple login page (frontend). In the following login.php page, I need to retrieve the entered username and password from the html page (I did this in the first 2 lines), then I need to pass both of this information to a backend (my partner). The backend expects a GET `username` and `password`, which apparently is the problem because I can't get it to be authenticated despite entering the correct username and password. I found that when I did `echo $response;` and `echo $var` in the code shown that nothing was returned and this might be the problem. Another potential problem is that the frontend POST data and the backend's expected GET data is incompatible.

```
<?php

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$_POST2 = ['username' => $username,
'password' => $password];

$ch = curl_init('https://wtfbbq.edu/blahblahblah.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST2);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;

curl_close($ch);

$var = json_decode($response, true);

echo $var;

if ($var['authenticated']){ // https://wtfbbq.edu/blahblahblah.php yields the following: {"authenticated":false,"success":false,"error":"Expected POST with username and password"}
echo 'You have successfully logged in.';
}
else{
    echo 'Failed login.';
}
```

Comment: So you're getting the `$username` and `$password` correctly.  You can echo the values?

Comment: why not this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);

Comment: @jothi I'm assuming he's naming the post values as they're named in the URL he's trying to post to.

Comment: OP, the only thing I can suggest is looking at the source code and making sure there's no input fields you haven't missed. Even the submit button. They are likely validating it all.

Comment: @SamOrozco Yes, after setting $_POST2 in the first 2 lines, `echo $_POST2['username'];
echo $_POST2['password'];` shows the username/password entered, as expected.

Comment: @jothi I set the post fields using $_POST2 so I'm using $_POST2 as a parameter (just in case there's any chance that it is unsafe to re-use $_POST from the previous lines.

Comment: _The backend expects a **GET** username and password..._ If it expects `GET` request, why do you send data as `POST`?